# Oracle APEX - How to create Checkbox which returns 'Y' when checked and 'N' when unchecked

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to create a checkbox which when clicked updates this column: terms_and_conditions.accepted. If the check box is checked then it sets value to 'Y' in column and is 'N' when unchecked/by default. My current code doesn't seem to mark as ‘Y’ when selected

I have this as the source:

[image]

and this as the dynamic action PL/SQL code:

[image]

Comment: What is the business flow ? page renders, user sees the checkbox and clicks (or does nothing and leaves it unchecked) and then clicks "Save" ?

Comment: What happens if you also **submit** P10_CC_OPTION in dynamic action (not just USER_ID)?